# Is there a programmatic way in CDK to set Cfn parameter values?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

In CDK, I know that I can set Cfn parameters on the cdk command line with the `--parameters` option (as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/parameters.html#parameters_deploy)).

My question is: can I do the same programmatically in my CDK app?

For example, I know that I can set context values on the cdk command line with the `--context` option, and I can do the same programmatically with the `construct.node.setContext()` method. I'm looking for such a facility to set Cfn parameters. I thought it might be in `cdk.Stack`, but I'm not finding anything. Thanks!

Comment: Currently in exactly the same scenario, were you able to find something to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer.

As I understand you tell about the following construction:

```js
    const yourValue = new CfnParameter(this, 'yourValueId', {
      type: 'String',
      description: 'Your value description',
      default: 'DefaultValue',
    });

    this.vpc = new Vpc(this, 'VpcForExample', {
      cidr: yourValue.valueAsString,
      // ...
    });
```

More information about it:

- https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cdk-parameters-example
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_core.CfnParameter.html

Comment: Thank you. This creates the parameter, but it does not set the value of the parameter at deploy-time. To set the parameter value, I only find the cdk --parameters option on the command line. I'm looking for a programmatic alternative to set the parameter value (not create the parameter).

Comment: You could simply change the default value for the parameter. But using CfnParameters is advised against - better to use regular props.